# @style/Theme.Translucent gives error

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a transparent background for my android app as stated here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html#style-themes

But I get this error:

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'theme' with value
>   '@style/Theme.Translucent').  AndroidManifest.xml /MyFirstApp line
>   23    Android AAPT Problem

My device is using Android 4.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a

```
@android:style/Theme.Translucent
```

not a

```
@style/Theme.Translucent
```

Actually, `Theme.Translucent` is part of **android platform resources style**.

When you are refer it by `@style/Theme.Translucent` its find in local resource directory. And there is not any style declared by you.

Comment: I used 
android:theme="style/Theme.Translucent" 
but I get 'string types not allowed'.
using @ in front of android throws up too many errors

Comment: Its a problem of your Android plugins in Eclipse. first check with restart eclipse or if not solved you can update your Android ADT. I think its problem of **aapt**.

Comment: Is this code correct?
<activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:theme="style/Theme.Translucent" >

Comment: First two lines are correct. But this one `android:theme="style/Theme.Translucent"` not.

Comment: @android:theme="style/Theme.Translucent"
gives several parse errors

Comment: You are misunderstood. its `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"`